# UI doesn't load, code still runs

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2, viewcontroller

Below is the offending code:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    doit("dave")
}
```

As a bit of background, the doit function is some code that will be running for a loooong time (days). When I run this code, the app bounces up and down for a while and while it's doing this, the print statements in the doit function start printing to the console.

But the UI never loads. The app icon stays in the dock, but there is no "open dot" as I call it.

If I take out the function, everything renders fine.

I can't think the code in the doit function should matter as the view should appear before it can even run. I've also tried it in viewDidLayout and viewDidLoad with the same results.

For fun I did this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(1)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidLayout() {
    super.viewDidLayout()
    print(2)
}
```

Both statements print without the view ever appearing.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If `doit` runs for a very long time, your problem is that you're blocking the main thread. Everything UI related happens there, but it can't happen because your `doit` function is still busy and the UI has to wait until it finishes. Your UI doesn't appear because `viewDidLoad` never returns, and it **must** return before other main-thread tasks can occur.

Long running functions should be put on other threads. Apple provides numerous ways to do this. Either GCD (i.e. `dispatch_async` and friends) or `NSOperation` are likely starting points for this.